# C# DateTime check is incorrect

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got a little problem with some code of mine. The case is as follows:

There is a ListView which contains some measurement data. One of the data items is a status. This status can be 10, 20 of 30. This depends on the value of the next measurement date.

What I do is this. I take the next measurement date and check if the current data + 3 month is higher then the next measurement date. If so, I return status 30.
If the current date >= the next measurement date, I should return 20.
Else I return 10.

So, in short:
current date + 3 months > next measurement date = status 30;
current date >= next measurement date = status 20;
else = status 10;

The problem is that when the next measement date is higher then the next measurement date, status 30 is allways returned. Below is my code:

```
private string getMsaStatus(DateTime dtNextMsa)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3) > dtNextMsa)
        {
            return "30";
        }
        else if (DateTime.Now >= dtNextMsa)
        {
            return "20";
        }
        else
        {
            return "10";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just revert the order you are using for the if and improve your accept ratio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change it like this:

```
if (DateTime.Now >= dtNextMsa.AddMonths(3))
{
    return "30";
}
else if (DateTime.Now >= dtNextMsa)
{
    return "20";
}
else
{
    return "10";
}
```

This code takes into account the clarification in your comment.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I applied your code but I get the same problem. the only difference is that the return status now is ether 10 or 20.

Comment: Shouldn't be the case. Maybe your test data is bogus? Example: If `dtNextMsa` would have the value of tomorrow, the code would return 30.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But how can I make this check then? The values must be like this:
When today is 3 or more month past the dtNextMsa date, then 30 must be returned.
When dtNextMsa is between today and over 3 months, then 20 must be returned.
In any other case, 10 must be returned.

Comment: @Bernhard you should unit test this, it's rather easy to unit test

Comment: @Oskar, I never did a unit test, so I will have to read up about it. That'll take me some time. But I'm certainly going to do the reading

Comment: @Bernhard you really should, for this case a unit test is perfect to see that your code returns what you want

Comment: @Daniel: Thank you so mutch! Your edited code works like a charm. I guess I was thinking the wrong way around. Thanks.